# How to install CUDA 9.1 on Mint 18.3?

Tags: linux-mint, software-installation, nvidia, cuda

I'm running Linux Mint 18.3 with the Cinnamon desktop environment, and I want to install CUDA 9.1 and NVIDIA drivers. How can I do that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have cuda 9.1 installed on Minty 18.3 with nvidia <strike>387</strike> 390 drivers.

This is what I did:

1. Use the driver manager to install nvidia 390 <strike>387 (for some reason, 390 isn't working)</strike>.  Note the pic shows 387, but 390 works now.

   [image]

Get the nvidia repo from:

```
wget http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu1704/x86_64/cuda-repo-ubuntu1704_9.1.85-1_amd64.deb
```

Install nvdia's repo and repo key for ubuntu 17.04:

```
sudo dpkg -i cuda-repo-ubuntu1704_9.1.85-1_amd64.deb
sudo apt-key adv --fetch-keys http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu1704/x86_64/7fa2af80.pub
```

Update apt's software index

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Install cuda

```
sudo apt-get install cuda
```

Edit:  one other thing.  If you build the samples, you need to set GLPATH environment variable to /usr/lib:  `export GLPATH=/usr/lib` before you run `make` in the samples dir.

see:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/34648972/356011