# How to install CUDA 9.2 on Linux Mint 19

Tags: ubuntu, linux-mint, cuda, machine-learning

I would like to install CUDA 9.2. on Linux Mint 19.

It was possible to [install CUDA on Linux Mint 18.3](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/433743/how-to-install-cuda-9-1-on-mint-18-3/435095) even though Linux Mint is not an [officially supported distribution](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-installation-guide-linux/#system-requirements). However, 
Linux Mint 18 was based on Ubuntu 16.04, while the newer Linux Mint 19 is based on Ubuntu 18.04  ([wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_Mint_version_history)).

Ubuntu 18.04 seems to have a [super easy solution](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1028830/how-do-i-install-cuda-on-ubuntu-18-04?rq=1) (most popular answer) which is also tempting but I would prefer to avoid switching distros if I can avoid it.

Comment: Hi, were you able to make this work?

Comment: I decided it was best to switch distros and have been using Ubuntu 18.04

Answer (score 0):

Linux Mint is derived from Ubuntu so much that works on one should work on the other.

Just try the "super easy solution" - the one that currently has 18 points, not the one that is the "accepted answer".

Comment: It tries to install `nvidia-driver-396` but is unable to find its dependencies.

Comment: "Linux Mint 19 installs Cuda 9.2 and cuDNN, NCCL" >>> https://siteinsights.co/2018/07/14/cuda-9-2-installation-on-Linux-mint-19/  NEED TO TRANSLATE!

Comment: I gave that a go but didn't work. There is obviously a typo at `export PATH=/usr/local/cuda/bin:$PAT` (i.e. should end in $PATH)

Comment: and when I got to this line `GLPATH="/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu" GLLINK="-L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu" DFLT_PATH="/usr/lib" EGLLIB="/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu" GLESLIB="/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu" make -j61` I am told that `make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found. Stop.
`